# How to Stop Spinner animating in iOS when no new data available in web services?

Tags: ios, json, uitableview

i make a spinner at the table view footer when i scroll table view then it was start animating and load next page data from web services but when my web services data was not more available then i want to make table view footer spinner stop animating how it possible please give me Solution.
Here my code for Data Parsing is

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
pageNum=0;
self.imageArray =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSURL * url=[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.truemanindiamagazine.com/webservice/news.php?page=%d",pageNum]];
}
dispatch_async(kBgQueue, ^{
    data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: url];
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fetchedData:) withObject:data waitUntilDone:YES];
});
}

}
-(void)fetchedData:(NSData *)responsedata
{
UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
spinner.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44);
self.newsTable.tableFooterView = spinner;
if (responsedata.length > 0)
{
    [spinner startAnimating];
    NSError* error;
    self.json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responsedata options:kNilOptions error:&error];
    if ([[_json objectForKey:@"data"] isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]])
    {
        NSArray *arr = (NSArray *)[_json objectForKey:@"data"];
        [self.imageArray addObjectsFromArray:arr];
        [self.newsTable reloadData];
        NSLog(@"images,%@",self.imageArray);
    }
    self.newsTable.hidden=FALSE;
}
```

And Table View Scroll Code is

```
 -(void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate
{
NSInteger currentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y;
NSInteger maximumOffset = scrollView.contentSize.height- scrollView.frame.size.height;
if (maximumOffset - currentOffset <= 0)
{
pageNum = pageNum + 1;
[self getData];
}
 }
-(void)getData
{
NSURL * url=[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.truemanindiamagazine.com/webservice/news.php?page=%d",pageNum]];
dispatch_async(kBgQueue, ^{
    data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fetchedData:) withObject:data waitUntilDone:YES];
});
}
```

Please Give Me Solution if it was Possible. And Second issue Is that When I scroll Table view then it Give me All Remaining Page Data then i want when i scroll then i get Second Page Data and When i Scroll next time then i got Third Page Data if any Possibility to make some time interval to load JSON Data of next Page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After getting response from server, check the response array count if its county is zero then make spinner stopanimating and spinner hidden yes. In else condition make if response array count is greater than zero, make spinner start animation and spinner hidden no. I hope this will helps you. I done my application like this and works for me perfectly. I also called pagination for my application.
Also if arraycount is zero, you can follow tableview footer following code

**self.theTable.tableFooterView = [UIView new];**

or

**self.tableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];**

All the best @Ashish Gabani

Answer (score 1):

You can add `[spinner stopAnimating]` at the end of fetchData method. You want to stop animating if you finish fetching data, right? Also, I think you should call startAnimating method in `getData`.

To do this, just add the spinner as a private property in the viewController and start animating it in `getData` and then stop it at the end of `fetchData`.

As general suggestion, instead of perform a selector. Take a look to `NSURLSessionDownloadTask` and use a block to retrieve the json dispatching to the main queue.

Comment: i solve my Spinner Animating issue but i want to know pagination parsing please help me.